# extract intensity profile along a line from image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

[image: ch4-out is the sample image]

I have a numpy array that contains some image data (ch4_out). Now, I want to extract intensity profile along a particular line (horizontal). I am using `profile_line` function from skimage module to do this, but I am getting error. I am seeking some help to resolve my code.

error displayed is

> order = _validate_interpolation_order(image.dtype, order)

```
# reading multiple images 
S01=[i for i in 
glob.glob("C:/Users/experiment/S01/*.tif")]

# Averaging images
ch4=np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in
S01])
ch4_avg=np.array(np.mean(ch4,axis=(0)),dtype=np.uint16)
ch4_out=Image.fromarray(ch4_avg) # image data as numpy array

#plotting figure
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(ch4_out,cmap='gray',interpolation='none') 
#code works fine until this point

#Now, extract intensity profile at pixel along horizontal line x (2 to 1000) at a height in vertical direction of 730 
pixels

p = profile_line(ch4_out, (2, 1000), (730, 730)) 
# coordinates for horizontal (2,1000) and vertical 
(730,730))
plt.imshow(p)
plt.show()
```

Comment: In which line are facing the error?

Comment: in line `p= profile_line(ch4_out,(),())`. basically, the code works fine for .jpg or .png or other image formats but not for numpy array having an image data as an array (Ch4_out is an numpy array ), I would prefer to use function such as `profile_line` for an array.

Comment: Based on [the documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.profile_line), ordering is important. That's what is mentioned in the error as well. How is your array ordered? Can you share sample image?

Comment: I have edited the post, the sample image is named ch4_out is attached to the question.

Comment: Shape of the array matters her @vashista. In line `ch4=np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in
S01])` you are forming an array of array this changes the desired input shape

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I use,

```
blob_img = io.imread(r"C:\Users\Oct_epb.tiff")
blob_img_arr = np.array(blob_img)# convert to array
# call the profile line module
start = (250, 0)#in Array co-ordinates
end = (100,blob_img_arr.shape[0]-1)
plt.grid(True)
profile = profile_line(blob_img_arr, start, end, linewidth=2)
# show the position of the line
io.imshow(blob_img, cmap='gray')
plt.plot([start[1],end[1]],[start[0],end[0]],'w--',lw=2)
plt.xlim(0,blob_img_arr.shape[0])
plt.show()
 #Profile line structure
plt.figure(figsize=(4.5,4.5))
plt.plot(profile,"k-")
plt.xlim(0,blob_img_arr.shape[0])
```